# Intermitent SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR when using Android hotspot

Tags: android, macos, google-chrome, ssl, xiaomi

When browsing the internet using the Wi-Fi hotspot of my Android phone (**Xiaomi Redmi Note 10 Pro**), some requests fail with the following error: `net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`

Here is a screenshot of the error I'm getting in **Chrome** for **Mac OS**:
[image: SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR on Chrome for Mac OS]

I noticed that it is happening only on specific websites (I have no issues on Stack Overflow for example).

This seems to be happening regardless of the LTE network quality.

I tried using the Wi-Fi hotspot from another phone, and everything is working as intended.

Anybody have an idea on how to debug this issue?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue, turns out the default APN was not correctly configured.

I re-configured my APN with the config given by my phone provider (for **Orange** in France, the config is here: https://assistance.orange.fr/mobile-tablette/tous-les-mobiles-et-tablettes/installer-et-utiliser/se-connecter-et-parametrer-un-reseau/se-connecter-a-un-reseau-mobile-3-4g/comment-ajouter-un-point-d-acces-internet-apn-sur-votre-mobile-xiaomi-sous-android-_321636-856633)